# Get Mode in XMPP/Smack

Tags: xmpp, asmack

My chat application has a procedure to set the presence/ mode status of the user i.e - Online, Offline, Invisible, Away etc. I am doing this using the following code :-

```
presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

            if (USER_STATE.equalsIgnoreCase("Online")) {
                presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
                setUserPresence(0);
            }else if (USER_STATE.equalsIgnoreCase("Invisible")) {
                presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.xa);
                setUserPresence(1);
            } else if (USER_STATE.equalsIgnoreCase("Away")) {
                presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.away);
                setUserPresence(2);
            } else if (USER_STATE.equalsIgnoreCase("Busy")) {
                presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.dnd);
                setUserPresence(3);
            }
```

Here when I set the User Presence to Away or Invisible etc. and log out the user. Now when the user is logged in again I want to get the mode of the User that he had set earlier since his last logout. I am getting it as :-

```
System.out.println("Loggeddd innn");
            // Set presence to online!
            Presence userPresence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            userPresence.setStatus("Hello CCM!");
            userPresence.setPriority(24);
            userPresence.setMode(userPresence.getMode());
            connection.sendPacket(userPresence);
```

Here I always get NULL in `user.getMode()` and also I always get Status as Available (shown in openfire portal)

Anybody please help ?

Answer (score 1):

`userPresence.setMode(userPresence.getMode())` seems like a no-op to me.

You should store the previous mode on the device itself (eg in `SharedPreferences`)

Comment: Okay, It is the only last option to do the same ?

Comment: Here my question is how the Gtalk is managing the same thing without locally saving the presence information ???
And what will happen if the user logs in to other device using the same credentials ?? If the presence is information is stored locally then how it be updated to the new mobile device in which user has logged in now ???

Comment: Let's try to be precise: presence (available) should never be stored locally.  A Presence packet may contain 1) <show> properties (dnd, away, chat and xa) which maps to the setMode Smack api. 2) <status> which is a text string.  I would be surprised if the server persists these but you can test this by a) logging in with userA and setting the status to "ABC" and logging out again b) logging in with userB (assuming A en B are friends) and see whether the incoming Presence packet for userB contains this status string

Comment: The presence packet always showing null when the logs out and logs in again. This is the main problem of me

Comment: @GauravArora: Hi,I am starting to create chat app. Can you guide me about where to start and what resources will I need? like server etc.

Comment: @MehulJoisar Hello, You require an Openfire Server dats it and rest of the things is you need to learn how to communicate with that server using Smack Library.

Comment: @GauravArora: is it going to charge me or everything is free?

Comment: @MehulJoisar Yes it is charged. 65$ per moth

Comment: @GauravArora: for any number of users? or any limitations? please provide some reference links if you have.I couldn't find pricing on OpenFire website.